# API request blocked by CORS policy

Tags: cors, postman

I'm trying to use a custom API provided by a client, its a login authentication API and when I test the URL on tools it works fine but when I call it in my code I receive this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api url' from origin 'http://localhost:5174' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
> "A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request ."

I have tried using chrome extensions but its the same issue, I've never worked with a custom APIs before so I'm not sure if its an issue from the server side, API provider or my code. How to check?

Comment: *"i'm not sure if its an issue from the server side"* - The server-side code needs to explicitly allow cross-origin requests.  Otherwise browsers will disallow those requests.  Sometimes you can make cross-origin requests if you don't need to be able to read the response, or you could use a client that isn't a web browser (e.g. Postman or a custom application), or perhaps create or find browser extensions which disable CORS restrictions, etc.  We don't really know the details of your system for any of that though.

Comment: I seen that error only when I add the wrong port or URL, but CORS errors 95% are the server's fault. If you have access to the server you should check to see their settings. The reason it works with postman and `curl` (it will work if you try it) , is due to the server settings configure to work that way